# Where to find secondary metabolites in lichen (and herbal medicine)?

Tags: database

I've searched around and found about 80 specific secondary metabolites for lichen, but I can't seem to find anymore. They were mostly from research papers. I read that there are more than 800 secondary metabolites of lichen. Is there some website that has all of them? I tried using HMDB but it yielded nothing.

Comment: It is a hard question to answer. Could you provide some search terms you used to find the database. Also, please clarify if you want a database about metabolites of lichen or from herbal medicine. Also if you could please post the reference of the 800 secondary metabolites it would be helpful too to see how they got that number

Comment: I suppose that will also depend on the lichen species (complex). This would be perhaps more suited for biology.SE.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't seem to be about bioinformatics at all.